# CSS hover menu closes after first option

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, menu

my CSS drop down menu looks perfect but when I hover the main selection, and then go to the first option it works, but then when I navigate to option 2, it closes. any space below option 1 it closes.

html:

```css
.dropdown{
position: relative;
}
.dropdown:after{
content: "\25BC";
font-size: .5em;
display: block;
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
right: 12%;
color:white;
}
.drop-nav{
position: absolute;
display: none;
background-color:#1A0D07;
 width:190px;
 list-style: none;padding: 0px;margin: 0px;
}
 .dropdown:hover > .drop-nav {
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="navigation">

 <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
 
 
 
 <li class="dropdown">
   <a href="character.html" class="active">Character List</a>
 <ul class="drop-nav">
  <center><li><a href="about.html">Fighter</a></li>
  <li><a href="updates.html">Priest</a></li>
  <li><a href="forum.html">Summoner</a></li>
  <li><a href="forum.html">Ranger</a></li>
  <li><a href="forum.html">Sorceress</a></li></center>
 </ul>
 </li>
 
 
 
 <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
 <li><a href="updates.html">Updates</a></li>
 <li><a href="forum.html">Forum</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

website is: 
http://corumvanadium.com/character.html

I've checked all help threads as well as the recommended ones before posting.

Answer (score 3):

try adding z-index to container ul(drop-nav)

```
.drop-nav{z-index: 999;}
```

Comment: something that took me all night was fixed that simply, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

use `z-index`

```
.drop-nav {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  background-color: #1A0D07;
  width: 190px;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  z-index: 10; /* <--- add z-index 10 or other value */
}
```

Comment: something that took me all night was fixed that simply, thank you!